# Sort strings by using "less/greater than" comparison operators in comparator

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

Today I found a strange for me implementation of strings sorting:

```
['Data', 'Chata', 'Clata'].sort(function(a, b) { return a > b});
```

Using this approach we take a valid sorted array as the output - `["Chata", "Clata", "Data"]`.
But I don't clearly understand why it works...

I know that comparator function expects three different outputs - zero, integer above zero, integer below zero. But in this case we can take only two values - **true** (if a greater than b) or **false** (if a less than b) (1 or 0 after type coercion).

Can anybody explain me why it works?

Comment: Think about 0. Does it matter? It is just some optimization.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure how it manages to work.

**EDIT** it actually doesn't.

I produced a test using 1000 numbers (https://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/80cje6gt/) and the single comparator doesn't produce the correct sort order:

```
var m = 0;
a.sort(function(a, b) { ++m; return a > b} );

var n = 0;
b.sort(function(a, b) { ++n; return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0});
```

Comment: I wonder if strings comparison can give us the same result (I mean that sorting by comparison works only for certain tests).

Comment: @user3429127  although my test used numbers instead of strings, the fundamental principle is the same - you *must* use a proper comparator.

Answer (score -1):

When comparing strings, comparison is done letter by letter. So `c` has lower symbol value than `d` ([Check this table](http://unicode-table.com/en/))

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question.