# javascript sorting array of objects by string property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort an array of object by a property `title`. This the code snippet that I am running but it does not sort anything. The array is displayed as it is. P.S I looked at previous similar questions. This one for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript) suggests and uses the same method I am using.

The javascript:

```
function sortLibrary() {
    // var library is defined, use it in your code
    // use console.log(library) to output the sorted library data
    console.log("inside sort");
    library.sort(function(a,b){return a.title - b.title;});
    console.log(library);
} 

// tail starts here
var library = [
    {
        author: 'Bill Gates',
        title: 'The Road Ahead',
        libraryID: 1254
    },
    {
        author: 'Steve Jobs',
        title: 'Walter Isaacson',
        libraryID: 4264
    },
    {
        author: 'Suzanne Collins',
        title: 'Mockingjay: The Final Book of The Hunger Games',
        libraryID: 3245
    }
];

sortLibrary();
```

The html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<h1> Test Page </h1>
<script src="myscript.js"> </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Bill Gates" - "Steve Jobs" should be what? Infinity or rather Not a Number ;)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried like this? It is working as expected

```
library.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : ((b.title > a.title) ? -1 : 0);} );
```

```js
var library = [
    {
        author: 'Bill Gates',
        title: 'The Road Ahead',
        libraryID: 1254
    },
    {
        author: 'Steve Jobs',
        title: 'Walter Isaacson',
        libraryID: 4264
    },
    {
        author: 'Suzanne Collins',
        title: 'Mockingjay: The Final Book of The Hunger Games',
        libraryID: 3245
    }
];
console.log('before sorting...');
console.log(library);
library.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : ((b.title > a.title) ? -1 : 0);} );

console.log('after sorting...');
console.log(library);
```

Comment: Is there any way to order this non-alphabetically, but based on another pre-set array? For example, order an entire list of names and functions but in the order of a pre-set array of functions ( chef above sous-chef, above chef de parties, ... ).

Answer (score 4):

Subtraction is for numeric operations. Use [`a.title.localeCompare(b.title)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) instead.

```js
function sortLibrary() {
  console.log("inside sort");
  library.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
  });
  console.log(library);
}

var library = [{
    author: 'Bill Gates',
    title: 'The Road Ahead',
    libraryID: 1254
  },
  {
    author: 'Steve Jobs',
    title: 'Walter Isaacson',
    libraryID: 4264
  },
  {
    author: 'Suzanne Collins',
    title: 'Mockingjay: The Final Book of The Hunger Games',
    libraryID: 3245
  }
];

sortLibrary();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the < or > operator when comparing strings in your compare function.

[see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Use the > operator for this instance, this works when replacing the minus operator with >.

Comment: @jonathan.ihm: The `.sort()` callback expects a numeric result, not a boolean, so more than just a drop-in replacement would be needed.

Comment: I ran it in console and confirmed it worked right away.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript

Comment: Nevermind, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466125/sort-strings-by-using-less-greater-than-comparison-operators-in-comparator as well

I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
library.sort(function(a, b){
var tA = a.title.toUpperCase();
  var tB = b.title.toUpperCase();
  if (tA < tB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (tA > tB) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

FOR DESC

```
library.sort(function(a,b){return a.title < b.title;});
```

or
FOR ASC

```
library.sort(function(a,b){return a.title > b.title;});
```