# Sort the Multidimensional array alpha numerically

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Here is my Array, I need to sort the second element

```
[{id:1,name:beta},
{id:2,name:alpha},
{id:3,name:charlie}]
```

How can i sort it like

```
[{id:2,name:alpha},
    {id:1,name:beta},
    {id:3,name:charlie}]
```

I tried like

```
roles = roles.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a[1] - b[1];
    });
```

and

```
roles = roles.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a.name - b.name;
    });
```

It doesn't sort like expected, as i have object inside the array. How can i do it ?

Comment: try -> `return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);`   A string minus a string really doesn't make much sense.. :)

Comment: // With underscore js 
var obj = [{id:1,name:"beta"},
{id:2,name:"alpha"},
{id:3,name:"charlie"}];

var result = _.sortBy(obj,"name");
console.log(result);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare `a.name` and `b.name` in your `sort` function.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'beta'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'alpha'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'charlie'
  }
];

arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return +(a.name > b.name);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Please be aware the `>` only short-cut may have issues -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466125/sort-strings-by-using-less-greater-than-comparison-operators-in-comparator

Comment: @Keith I never realized that, thanks for the heads up !

Comment: In typescript it shows error, can you please fix for it too

Comment: @SA__ Works fine for me. What's the error?

Comment: It shows this error , Please see in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVbPh.png

Comment: @SA__ I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy  :) +1 and accepting answer

Comment: Won't it work , if i have arrays more than 500+ ? It seems working in small number and not in large number

Comment: @SA__ It should work just fine.